# Create dynamic Id in Thymleaf

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I am creating a dynamic id in `Thymleaf` using a dynamic variable

```
 <img th:src="@{/assets/img/ico-warning.svg}" alt="" th:id="'selection_warning_img_'+${addOn.name}">
```

But the problem is that `addOn.name` contains `space`.That's why it's not working when I am accessing the element with `id`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use

```
th:id="'selection_warning_img_'+${addOn.name.replaceAll(' ', '')}"
```